# Nivo Slider occasionally jumping

Tags: html, css, position, slideshow, nivo-slider

My slider works, but occasionally the slides will jump down about 40px, and then correct themselves.

The page in question is:  http://www.streetstyles4all.co.uk

I had to watch it a few times around for it to happen, but it happens in firefox, chrome, and IE9

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that there is some text above the images/links.

> end-of-year-show-bg-2012

you could try removing that. After deleting it with Chrome dev tools I couldn't reproduce the problem again...

Comment: Thank you so much!  Silly really, I think my eyes are so tired which is why I missed it!